# Install 'standard' packages

Tags: debian, apt

Normally during the setup you can choose which group packages you'd like to install.
However I'm running a LXC Debian container, so I am missing a LOT of standard packages (even iputils was missing for example.)

How do I install all the 'Standard' packages, without naming them one by one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by running [tasksel](https://wiki.debian.org/tasksel).

> Tasksel package provides a simple interface for users who want to configure their system to perform a specific task. This program is used during the installation process, **but users can also use tasksel at any time**.

[image]

=== **Update**

Packages marked as required and important (such as iptables) are normally installed by [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap). If they are missing you can install them by creating files listing these packages with:

```
aptitude search ~prequired -F"%p" > required.list
aptitude search ~pimportant -F"%p" > important.list
```

You can then edit these lists according to your needs and install them with:

```
cat required.list | xargs sudo apt-get install
cat important.list | xargs sudo apt-get install
```

Comment: This does not seem to have the packages like iptables, iputils, etc?